# Multiple images from folder

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

as I'm fairly new to C# and WPF I just can't figure out how to do this. I have a form that should show 151 images (all pokemon generation 1 sprites) in a form. The way I've done it now is that it shows the same image 151 times instead of all images just once. The code I wrote for this is as follow:

```
    public partial class PokeGame : Window
{
    BitmapImage carBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/All_Sprites/001.png", UriKind.Absolute));

    {

        InitializeComponent();

        int imgCount = 151;
        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;
        List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();
        for (int i = 0; i < imgCount; i++)
        {
            if(i % 10 == 0)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    top += 175;
                    left = 0;
                } else
                {
                    top = 0;
                    left = 0;
                }
            }

            Image img_ding = new Image();
            img_ding.Source = carBitmap;
            img_ding.Height = 150;
            img_ding.Width = 150;
            img_ding.Margin = new Thickness(left, top ,0 ,0);
            imageList.Add(img_ding);
            left += 175;
        }

        int j = 0;

        foreach (Image img in imageList)
        {
            imageCanvas.Children.Add(img);
            j++;
        }

    }
```

As you can see there's probably lots of room for improvement in my code. However, my question is: How can I make it so that it doesn't display the same image 151 times but all images (sprite001.png, sprite002.png, sprite003.png, etc.)?

Comment: You're calling `img_ding.Source = carBitmap;` 151 times in a loop. So what is your expectation? Besides that, you should use an ItemsControl instead of programatically adding Image controls to a Canvas.

Comment: Sigh. Now you have three answers telling you the same, all of them still have the redundant `UriKind.Absolute`, but none showing how to use an ItemsControl. I'd write one later if you're interested. Your code behind would drop to one line.

Comment: Thanks alot for offering. I've got the solution down now and will probably try out the other suggestions aswell for training purposes. Also, I fixed the     img_ding.Source = carBitmap;     line now. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your bitmap inside the loop, not outside. Then each iteration will create a new bitmap with the new path.

so something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgCount; i++)
{
   // padding left will give you 001 and 010 and 151
   string img = i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0');
   BitmapImage carBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/All_Sprites/" + img+".png", UriKind.Absolute));
   // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It's so easy this way and it does exactly what I want it to do :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of programmatically adding Image controls to a Canvas, write this XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="images">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Probably add some `Margin` to the Image control in the DataTemplate.

In code behind, add one line to the constructor of your MainWindow:

```
using System.Linq;
...

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    images.ItemsSource = Enumerable
        .Range(1, 151)
        .Select(i => string.Format("pack://application:,,,/Images/{0:000}.png", i));
}
```

---

Now you might want to create a proper view model, where you would have a collection-type property for your images, like

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Images { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>(Enumerable
            .Range(1, 151)
            .Select(i => string.Format("pack://application:,,,/Images/{0:000}.png", i)));
}
```

You would then assign the Window's DataContext to an instance of the view model, and bind to the collection property like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for commenting! I got it all done using @darren answer but I will try this aswell for learning purposes!

Comment: If you're going to continue with WPF, there won't be a way around XAML,  data templates and data binding. The earlier you start to do it right, the better.

Answer (score 4):

You create `carBitmap` exactly once, outside the loop, and use it every time. Create a new one for each image instead.

```
        Image img_ding = new Image();
        BitmapImage carBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/All_Sprites/001.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        img_ding.Source = carBitmap;
```

I assume that path ending in `001.jpg` should be changing each time; no doubt you can figure that out. Is it the value of `i` in the for loop, stringified and left-padded with zeroes? That'd look like this:

```
        Image img_ding = new Image();
        var uri = String.Format("pack://application:,,,/Images/All_Sprites/{0:000}.png", i);
        //  N.B. UriKind.Absolute is redundant, sigh
        BitmapImage carBitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute ));
        img_ding.Source = carBitmap;
```

Also, @Clemens is going to provide an answer that shows you how to rewrite the whole thing using an `ItemsControl`, which will be much nicer than this. I already wrote somebody a bunch of XAML this morning so it's his turn.

Comment: oooo. haven;t seen that way of formatting before with `{0:000}` - that do the same as padleft?

Comment: @Darren Yep, sure will.

Comment: Hey, that isn't a bunch of XAML, just 12 lines :-)