# A Grid of Images WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I have a list of employees:

```
List<Employees> staff = new List<Employees>();
```

Each employee has the property:

```
staff.name
staff.image_path
```

This is used to get these details:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}

public string ImagePath
{
    get { return file_name; }
    set { file_name = value; }
}
```

The image_path contains the employees directory with the picture of the staff member. I am aiming for a grid with all of the staff's pictures on them. I'm not sure on how to achieve this. What WPF control should I be using?

Comment: You could use an ItemsControl: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

Comment: Use a UniformGrid as ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl, as e.g. shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024424/1136211

Comment: @Clemens I don't really understand what's going on here...Is ItemsControl a WPF Control? Do I manually copy and paste that section into the XAML?